# ImageView does not display image from specific folder

Tags: android, image, imageview

I've problem when I use ImageView to display an image from sdcard. I tried many code, those below, but no one works for me, knowing that The activity run without any problem "success" but the screen is always empty and does not show the image. Any idea. Thanks in advance.

activity_mainvie.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".IMAGEVIE" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Codes tried for the main activity are:

```
public class IMAGEVIE extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagevie);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/life.jpg");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
}
```

The second code:

```
 public class IMAGEVIE extends Activity {

    private File mFichier;
    private Uri fileUri;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagevie);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        File f= new File("/sdcard/life.jpg");
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
}
```

The third code:

```
public class IMAGEVIE extends Activity {

    private File mFichier;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagevie);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);  
        mFichier = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"life.jpg");

        if(mFichier.exists())
        {
            iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(mFichier));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the file exists?

Comment: yes, it's exist. And I've the same problem when I use GridView. Always an empty screen without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your path to sdcard is wrong it should be like this:

```
 File f= new File("/mnt/sdcard/life.jpg");
```

Comment: Hi, the same problem persists when I change the path.

Comment: do you have this permission in your MANIFEST.XML? 

<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: No, I'll try it in minute.

Answer (score 1):

**first** : you are saving you xml file as activity_main.xml

so change setContentView to :-

setContentView(R.layout.**activity_main**);

in your java file !

**than**
try this :

```
  File f = new File(strImgPath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(strImgPath);
            iv.setImageDrawable(d);

        }
```

its working for me

where **strImgPath is a String variable** which contains path of your image !

and also check have u added the permission in you AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; It's done but it does not work also!!! I don't understand where is the problem!!

Comment: Have you tried to change setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagevie); to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: No, I didn't because the Xml file for layout is named activity_imagevie.xml I don't understand why I should rename it? can you explain to me please! thanks in advance.

Comment: ok than there is no need to rename it ! i was recommending this because you listed the file name activity_main.xml at the starting of your question before your xml contents:                              Your question was : -  _ I've problem when I use ImageView to display an image ........ Thanks in advance.

** activity_main.xml ** _

Comment: I'm new on this site, I found problem even for close the question @Tarsem. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your content view to R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made mistake it's not activity_main.xml but it's activity_mainvie.xml  "name of xml file in layout folder". So the code still the same without changes!

Answer (score 0):

First save image:

`if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(sdCard + "/folder");

        myDir.mkdir();

        FSApi.snapPic(myDir+"/img");

}`

Then open it:

```
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/folder/");
            allFiles = folder.listFiles();
            if (allFiles == null) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("No such a file/directory");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
                alertDialog.show();

            }
            // Folder is empty
            else if (allFiles.length == 0) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("No snapshot to display");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
                alertDialog.show();

            }
            // Folder contains files
            else {
                new SingleMediaScanner(Activity.this, allFiles[0]);
            }
        }


public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        mMs.disconnect();
    }
}
```